# Writing files from browser without service or server

Tags: javascript

I want to read and write a file localy on my computer from the browser. I am pretty sure that this not working but you never know.

So here is what i currently have to test whether my wish is possible. It's pretty much the angularjs demo with some adaptions.

```
function TodoController($scope, $http) {
    $http.get('data.json')
        .then(function(res){
            $scope.todos = res.data;                
    });

    $scope.save = function(){
        $http.put('data.json', $scope.todos).
            success(function(data){
                alert(data);
            }).
            error(function(data){
                alert("error");
            });
    };

    $scope.addTodo = function() {
        $scope.todos.push({text:$scope.todoText, done:false});
        $scope.todoText = '';
    };
...
}
```

I get the content of the json file with .get and i tried to save the content of $scope.todos with .put and .post. Are there any chance to write files without having a service or server? Maybe with a browser extention? Or did I something wrong?

Comment: http://www.html5rocks.com/en/features/file_access, there are ways but you will have to ask the user first, but there are other ways like localstorage to store data on the client

Comment: also http://html5-demos.appspot.com/static/a.download.html